# Stubbing function with jest to test Internal error

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs

I'm trying to test a controller function using jest, and i want to test all three status return

```
const messagesSender = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { message } = req.body;
    if (!message) {
      return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Message cannot be null' });
    }
    return res.status(200).send(message);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Error' });
  }
};

module.exports = { messagesSender };
```

Test file:

```
const messages = require('../controller/messagesController');

describe('Testing Messages Controller', () => {

  it('should return internal error', async () => {
    const req = {
      body: {
        message: 'testing',
      },
    };
    const res = {
      send: jest.fn(),
      status: jest.fn(() => res),
    };
    const messageResponse = await messages.messagesSender(req, res);
    messageResponse.mockImplementation(() => {
      throw new Error('User not found');
    });
    expect(res.status).toBeCalledWith(500);
  });
});
```

But i'm receiving the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'mockImplementation' of undefined
```

How can i fix this and test the 500 result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  it('should return internal error', async () => {
    const req = {
      body: {
        message: 'testing',
      },
    };
    const res = {
      send: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        throw new Error('User not found');
      }),
      status: jest.fn(() => res),
    };
    await messages.messagesSender(req, res);
    expect(res.status.mock.calls[1][0]).toBe(500);
  });
```

In your case `send` function returning nothing and causing this problem. In this case `status` method have been called twice, so you need to check the second call.